# Using custom fonts with Google Web Toolkit

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to utilize a custom font in a Google Web Toolkit web application. I have tried following the documentation / code available at https://code.google.com/p/gwt-webfonts/, but I am still having problems. I did not fully understand what I needed to do.

I have:

1. Included the gwt-webfonts-0.1.jar file dependency in my project
2. Added an include dependency to my gwt.xml file:
3. Created an extension of ClientBundle:

   ```
   import com.google.gwt.dev.javac.testing.impl.MockResource;
   import com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.FileResource;
   import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle;
   import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle.Source;
   import com.google.gwt.resources.client.CssResource;
   import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;

   public interface MainClientBundle extends ClientBundle
   {
      @Source("LesJoursHeureux.otf")
      public FontResource myFont();

   };
   ```
4. In my ui.xml file, I included a reference to the font resource:

   ```
   <ui:style type='com.example.TopMenuView.TopMenuViewStyle'>
       .maintitle {
           font-family: value('myFont.getFontName');
       }
   </ui:style>
   ```
5. This is where I didn't exactly know what to do. In my TopMenuView.java class, I included this snippet:

   ```
   private static MainClientBundle MY_RESOURCES = GWT.create(MainClientBundle.class);
   {
       MY_RESOURCES.myFont().ensureInjected();
   }
   ```
6. When I try to build the project, I receive this error:

   ```
   Creating assignment for style()
        [java]  Performing substitution in node font-family : .....
        [java]  [ERROR] Could not find no-arg method named myFont in type com.example.TopMenuView_TopMenuViewUiBinderImpl_GenBundle
   ```

EDIT: I am using version 2.6.0 of the GWT SDK.

Comment: What version of GWT are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution without any external library.

First, declare a `DataResource` in your `MainClientBundle.java`:

```
@MimeType("application/font-sfnt") // use appropriate mime type depending on font file format
@Source("aller/aller_rg-webfont.ttf")
DataResource allerRegularTtf();
```

Import your `DataResource` in your css file, using GSS (GWT >= 2.7.0):

```
@def ALLER_REGULAR_TTF resourceUrl("allerRegularTtf");
```

or using classic CssResource (GWT < 2.7.0):

```
@url ALLER_REGULAR_TTF allerRegularTtf;
```

In your `.css` file, declare an `@font-face` and use it:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "AllerRegular";
  src: ALLER_REGULAR_TTF format("truetype");
}

.myClass {
  font-family: "AllerRegular";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have tried this approach (using a .ttf file instead of an .otf) with no luck so far. The font of the DOM element with the font-family styling remains unchanged. Do I need to declare an instance of MainClientBundle anywhere in my code in order for this to work?

Comment: Have you made sure to call `mainClientBundle.style().ensureInjected()` somewhere at your application startup?

Comment: Oh, I took that out of my code since it wasn't mentioned in your solution. I'll put it back in and give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I think there may be a problem with performing the ensureInjected() call. Since the 'style()' (allerRegularTtf() in your example) method is a DataSource datatype, it does not have the ensureInjected() method available. I tried casting it to a CssResource datatype just to see what would happen, but it did not like that either. I got a ClassCastException. Am I missing something? Thanks again.

Comment: The method `com.google.gwt.resources.client.CssResource#ensureInjected` is not defined for `DataResource`. You have to call `ensureInjected()` on a `CssResource`, not `allerRegularTtf()`.

Comment: Oops, I meant 'style'()' is a DataResource datatype, not DataSource.

Comment: I was not able to get this working in my case and I had to abandon it due to time constraints. However, since @robert seems to have had success with it I have marked the answer as accepted. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: With GWT 2.8.2 this approach worked for me with '@url' but not with '@def'.

Answer (score 1):

[SPGs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28509467/418057) answer is the best, however, if you don't want to mess around with GWT resource bundles, you can put your font in your war directory, then in your index.html define the font:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: MyFont;
        src: url(myfont.ttf);
    }
</style>
```

Then you set the font family to MyFont (or whatever you called it).  Eg:

```
myLabel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("fontFamily", "MyFont");
```